# Why is Javascript not redirecting to correct path on production server?

Tags: javascript, client-side

I am trying to redirect to another page using a relative path like this:

```
window.location.href = "/admin/page";
```

In my local machine, this works well, as I get redirected to `localhost:8000/admin/page`. On my production server, however, I get redirected to `https://admin/page` instead of `https://example.com/admin/page`. Any ideas on why does this happen?

Comment: In what browser/OS, I've just tested on this page in console in Google Chrome on Windows 10 and it works fine. Do you have this server public?

Comment: use `window.location.href ="https://example.com/admin/page"`.

Comment: @jcubic the server is private, that is why I used an example.

Comment: This is not standard behavior of the browser (just open console in this page - press F12, and type this code into console), you need to have something wrong with browser or with the server. Or you didn't show your real code. Without seeing the server where this behavior can be observed I afraid nothing I can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the full url

```
window.location.href = location.origin+"/admin/page";
```